# xhci_pci slows down applications on start

Tags: drivers, kernel, blacklist, xhci-hcd

I recently installed kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a ASUS laptop with AMD Ryzen 9 7845HX and RTX 4060 GPU, and unfortunately many applications are extremely slow to start. With top I noticed that there are kworkers processes that sometimes can take almost 100% of the CPU. Following instructions from other answers I found that I could solve the delay issue by disabling the module xhci_pci:

`sudo modprobe -r xhci_pci`

In this way the delay on application start can go down in some cases from something around a minute to a fraction of a second...  Unfortunately, when I do this the keyboard becomes completely inactive. Is there a way to blacklist this module without disabling the keyboard? What other problems could I have if I blacklist that module?

Comment: The problem seems to be solved after upgrading the BIOS firmware. For a more detailed discussion about this problem, see https://community.frame.work/t/tracking-kworker-stuck-at-near-100-cpu-usage-with-ubuntu-22-04/23053/2

Comment: Please post answers as actual answers, not comments

Comment: I spoke too soon. After some time the problem arose again. I would be happy to have an answer, but I don't. From what I understand, it's a bug that hasn't been fixed yet https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1990876 . A workaround is to shut down the module xhci_pci, as I said, but unfortunately in my case this also deactivate the keyboard. So my question is still open.